# Flutter - Trying to use a void Function to return a String

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am trying to return a String using a function but i kept getting 
'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 269 pos 10: 'data != null''

This is my String function:

```
test<String>(String callsign) {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('Manning')
        .getDocuments()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
        if (f.data.containsKey('Paramedic') && f.documentID == callsign) {
          return f.data['Paramedic'];
        } else if (f.data.containsKey('Medic') && f.documentID == callsign) {
          return f.data['Medic'];
        } else if (f.data.containsKey('Driver') && f.documentID == callsign) {
          return f.data['Driver'];
        } else if (f.data.containsKey('Attachment') &&
            f.documentID == callsign) {
          return f.data['Attachment'];
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

I've tried returning a Future but that cant be placed inside a Text widget.

Comment: Welcome to the world of async programming. You're going to need a FutureBuilder there.

Comment: Or define a String parameter in your stateful widget, use `setState` to set its value within the function shown above, and check its value within `build` to return either a `Text` widget or a placeholder if you don't have the string value yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually returning anything.

You have 2 ways of doing it:

The best way is returnig a future and using it inside a [FutureBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo)

OR

Passing a callback to the function and updating some state on callback call like:

```
test<String>(String callsign, void Function(String) callback) {
  Firestore.instance
    .collection('Manning')
    .getDocuments()
    .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
      if (f.data.containsKey('Paramedic') && f.documentID == callsign) {
        callback(f.data['Paramedic']);
      } else if (f.data.containsKey('Medic') && f.documentID == callsign) {
        callback(f.data['Medic']);
      } else if (f.data.containsKey('Driver') && f.documentID == callsign) {
        callback(f.data['Driver']);
      } else if (f.data.containsKey('Attachment') &&
        f.documentID == callsign) {
        callback(f.data['Attachment']);
      }
    }));
  });
}
```

and passing as callback something like

```
test("", (value) => setState(...))
```

inside a stateful widget